# How can I select multiple check boxes within a drop down using python and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have an internal web page that has what appears to be a text box which has a drop down and check boxes.

I am not familiar with web page source code so bear with me on that explanation and have very little Selenium experience.

The code I posted below will select FOO without any problem but throws an error when  both FOO and BAR.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_xpath(".<some valid path here>.")).click()
    sites_checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(sites_checkbox['FOO']))

if not sites_checkbox.is_selected():
    sites_checkbox.click()

sites_checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(sites_checkbox['BAR']))

if not sites_checkbox.is_selected():
    sites_checkbox.click()
```

If I run the lines independently I can select either FOO or BAR but if I run the code above I get the error:

```
sites_checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(sites_checkbox['AVC']))
```

TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable

Manually I can select multiple checkboxes without any issues. I tried waiting a long time between the code and that didn't effect the error.